# Has the theory of 'cognitive spaces' ever produced any practical uses?

Tags: pybrain

The theory of cognitive spaces says that not only do we navigate through space using our hippocampus (with its grid cells and place cells), but that we represent abstract concepts that way too, and (I think) solve problems by navigating through these other, conceptual feature spaces.   Has anyone created a machine learning algorithm based on these ideas?